# Filter out string column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Here is my query, to locate a single record in table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Tests.Release, Tests.Result FROM Tests WHERE 
  Tests.TestCaseID = 104209
    ORDER BY Tests.Release
```

`Tests.Release` is a column, containg alphanumeric values, which are not comparable using numerical comparision operators. I want to filter out records from my query, based on one known release string and whatever is sorted above that record. If that release were a string I would write `WHERE Tests.Release > 10`. But again, my release is complex string, which can be only sorted.

Update as requested:

```
Release
-------
A1B
A2B
A3B---^
A4B
A5B
```

Known release is `A3B`. So I need to look for my row within `A2B` and `A1B`

Comment: Can you define further `whatever is sorted above that record`?  How is it sorted?

Comment: @JNK: Updated. Let me know if it's still not clear. Thx

Comment: @michael - is this actual example data?  I'm asking because that should sort with regular inequality `<` `>` operators.

Comment: @JNK: It's pretty close, also may contain `.` and `,`. Would comparision work for something like `A1B.Z2C,001` ? In which case comparision operators will not do the job(within the scope of my problem)?

Comment: @Michael - You can use a `LEFT` function to just look at the significant digits, i.e. `WHERE LEFT(Release, 3) < 'A3B'.`

Comment: @JNK: All digits and numbers are significant and may have various offsets, can't go parse the whole release string, sorry :(

Comment: @michael - Then if you need to run a comparison operator on that irregular of a string, you have a data design issue.  think about breaking  the components of that string out into different fields.

Comment: @JNK: Too many changes are related to that. Can't go that way...

Comment: @Michael - if your current architecture won't work for what you are trying to do, and you aren't willing to change the architecture, then I guess you are at an impasse.

Comment: @JNK: There should be some string comparision operators in SQL. I can compare strings in most of the languages or at least to give me facility to do it by calling some external predicate?

Comment: @michael - can you give me two examples of actual data strings and what evaluation you want to make?

Comment: @JNK: `A1B.Z2C`, `A1C.Z2C`, `A1D.Z2C` and `A1E.Z2C` are to samples of actual string. Given by `A1D.Z2C` only search in first two items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use comparison operators on a string.  They follow the normal access text collation rules as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129719

```
SELECT Tests.Release, Tests.Result
FROM Tests
WHERE Tests.TestCaseID = 104209 AND Tests.Release <='A1B2C2'
ORDER BY Tests.Release
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Tests.Release will not fall into a sortable historical list without complex manipulation, I would add a timestamp column and date each release and sort by that instead.

Comment: Releases may be added out of chronological order.

Comment: The sorted order is perfectly fine to filter the records.